Thruk 3.20-1 : no way to embedded other page with menu_local.conf
I try to embendded page with menu_local.conf with this functions :

insert_item
insert_sub_item
add_link

i use 'target' => 'main' in the json but when i click the link in the menu the page appear in another tab.
Someone have an idea
thanks
I try to use 'target' => '_blank' for an other windows but appear in another tab too and not in an other windows.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
